# Linux - Print specific line from output

Tags: linux, bash, printing

I am used to working with single line output and can use $1 $4 $8 to specify certain items in that line, but I have never worked with multiple line outputs and would like to just print one line instead of all of it to a log file. Here is the output I am working with:

```
# bitcoind getinfo
{
"version" : 80100,
"protocolversion" : 70001,
"walletversion" : 60000,
"balance" : 0.00000000,
"blocks" : 352256,
"connections" : 0,
"proxy" : "",
"difficulty" : 49446390688.24143982,

"paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
"errors" : ""
}
```

I would like to print just the "balance" : 0.00000000," line to a log file, right now I have all of the output going to the log file with the time ran. I am just not sure how to print a line from an output that is not single line.

Why did I get a downvote, i am new to Linux and dont know every command out there

Comment: You want `grep`

Comment: well ok! I was stuck on using awk and print with $1 $2 etc...

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: You could do it with awk just fine `awk '/pattern/ {print}'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hyppy stated you need to use grep in any of these ways:

1. Against a file: `grep balance filename`
2. At the end of a pipe:  `somecommand | grep balance`
3. With extended regex : `grep -E '^"balance":'`